# Adding new window Properties in Response.Redirect

Tags: javascript, c#

I converted following javascript code which used to redirect to another page into c# code(server side) with the help of Response.Redirect

javascript is this.

```
function GetBillDetails() {
    var childWindow = null;
    var SelVal = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
    var SelText = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;
    childWindow = window.open('../Mine/MyPrint.aspx?BillNo=' + SelVal + '&Bill=' + SelText +, "MainForm", "width=725px,height=530px,left=150px,top=50px,scrollbars=no,toolbars=no,resizable=no")
}
```

and C# code with Response.Redirect is,

```
string BillNo = "255", Bill = "CG2/78";
Response.Redirect("../Mine/MyPrint.aspx?BillNo=" + BillNo + "&Bill='" + Bill + ");
```

It works fine. But my question is how to add those new window properties in Response.Redirect as used in javascript code

```
"width=725px,height=530px,left=150px,top=50px,scrollbars=no,toolbars=no,resizable=no"
```

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/317410/Response-Redirect-into-a-new-window

Comment: Thanks it perfectly works

Answer (score 0):

Instead of response.redirect,  try this:

```
Response.write("<script>");
Response.write("window.open('YOUR_PAGE_WITH_PARAM','_blank')");
Response.write("</script>");
```

OR

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'> window.open('YOUR_PAGE_WITH_PARAM', 'window','HEIGHT=600,WIDTH=820,top=50,left=50,toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');</script>");
```

Comment: But It didn't redirect. I used above suggested article

Comment: I tried this code before but nothing happened. It doesn't show any error but popup didn't come.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, but I already got a solutions from Subhash post